# How to fix problem of same keys in same element using twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which I use twice: so React read its keys as a
same value:

***App.tsx***

```
<>
    <Module/>
    <Module/>
</>
```

**Module.tsx**

```
{props.advantages.map((i, idx) =>
    <div key={idx}>
        {i}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `i` instead of `idx` as a key?

Comment: I have some i with the same value @RubenSmn

Comment: "_same element using twice?_" - what does it exactly mean? Show us whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I'm learning React Native but this is my alternative:

**App.tsx**

```
 <>
    <Module type="not"/>
    <Module type="the-best"/>
    <Module type="alternative"/>
 </>
```

**Module.tsx**

```
{props.advantages.map((i, idx) =>
    var newKey = `${props.type}-${idx}`
    <div key={newKey}>
        {i}
    </div>
)}
```

Best regards.